# Force identityserver to use a specific schema on a specifc client

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-identity, openid-connect, identity

I have an duende identityserver that has multiple BFFs as a client.
One of these BFFs is for my admins.

My identityserver has multiple sign in schemes (Think facebook, google etc) however i want to force my Administrator bff to use the (Azure AD (for my organization only) login.

I was thinking maybe setting clientproperties in the database and having the identityserver respond to that. But i was wondering if there is a more standard way of doing it that I haven't thought about.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fun fact:

Duende identityserver has Client.IdentityProviderRestrictions

this is excactly what i needed for my goal

Answer (score 0):

Some authorization servers have `allowed authenticator` settings, though others do not. I could not see a built in option in the [client model](https://docs.duendesoftware.com/identityserver/v5/reference/models/client/).

Another option is for the client application (your BFF) to send the [acr_values](https://docs.duendesoftware.com/identityserver/v6/reference/endpoints/authorize/) OpenID Connect request parameter to force that app to bypass authentication selection screens.

This feels like the preferred option in your case. After login  your BFF could even validate the [acr claim](https://openid.net/specs/openid-connect-core-1_0.html#IDToken) to check that the expected authentication method(s) was used.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, i feel that if i use the client properties i can enable server side permissions.

Comment: Makes sense - express allowed authenticators in client properties. Curious - do you then need to write custom code to enforce this behaviour?

Comment: Im not to sure yet, but i think it will be changes in the razor pages of the frontend